# Dangers of Heating a Bedroom up to High Temp

Tags: heat

In order to kill bedbugs and clothes moths, I was thinking of putting portable heaters in my bedroom and raising temperature to 120 degrees for an hour or so.   If I take out thinks like alarm clock and radio's, would it be safe for other structural elements, furniture, and lamps in the bedroom?
Thx in advance,
J

Comment: I don't think you're going to catch anything on fire at 120F.  Drywall paper should be around 450F flashpoint, wiring insulation should be 350F or so.

One thing I'd watch for is overdrawing your circuit in that bedroom if they're electric heaters.  Resistively heating a room to 120F is going to take some current, and you might trip breakers.

Comment: Bedbugs hide in well-insulated areas.  You would probably need to heat the room for a good day to raise the temperature of the areas where the bugs hide.  Are you sure that 120 degrees will reliably kill them?

Answer (score 3):

You mostly want to protect yourself and pets from harm:

> As you can imagine, you do not want to be in the home while it is this hot. Not only does this give the bugs a way to escape by climbing onto you and the going with you when you leave, but it can pose health problems.
>
> Even when you are in a sauna that reaches these same temperatures, you are not inside for nearly so long. You will have to find a time when no one needs to be home for the duration of the treatment if you want to begin killing bugs with heat. If you have the time, this is very much worth it.

Obviously you'll want to remove anything sensitive to heat, such as candles, personal products, and food.

However, you'll need to do a fair bit better than 120 degrees:

> Generally speaking, your home will have to be heated up to 140°F and held at this temperature for two hours. Alternatively, you could have the home brought up to a temperature of 130°F and held at that level for three hours.

So 120 degrees probably won't do it. Also, if you're just doing one room, you're probably going to see a quick resurgence of the critters.

http://www.bedbugs.org/heat